# VueJS Jquery Datatable Integration: Attach method to dynamic html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, vue.js, vuejs2

I integrated Jquery Datatables with VueJS [Here](https://codepen.io/saadbinmahbub/pen/VMWORE?editors=1010) is my Code

I want to attach a method of my Vue compoenent to the `button` `My Button`:

`row.push('<button @click="vm.buttonPressed()">My Button</button>'); //Add a method when button is pressed`

How would I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you ever tried building your table using Vue `v-for` directive for rendering the rows and then just invoking `DataTable` method on the resulting table?

That would be:

1. Build your table and rows as you would normally do by using Vue components.
2. Create a "DataTable" from it like so: `$('#example').DataTable();`

Take a look at this modified version I made from yours:

https://codepen.io/feload/pen/PJKoJP?editors=1010

Good luck!

Comment: works but this will not update datatable's row if data updates in vue.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind a wrapper component is to separate the parts of the DOM that Vue gets to control from those that something else will control. Inside the `data-table` component, jQuery is in control of the DOM. Handle your events accordingly:

```
$(this.$el).on('click button', (event) => {
  this.buttonPressed();
});
```